# how to get all content (HTML Code) of any web page not in my server by php

Tags: php, html, curl, get

how to get all content (HTML Code) of any web page not in my server by php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two simple methods to print out the content (HTML) of the google.com home-page:

1. Using [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents)

---

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/");
echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars($content).'</pre>';
?>
```

If this method fails (due to URL fopen wrappers not enabled, use second method below).

2. Using [`cURL`](https://www.php.net/curl):

---

```
<?php
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

$content = file_get_contents_curl("http://www.google.com/");
echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars($content).'</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: @faresoft, I have fixed a typo in #2, please try it now. Not working of #1 is very common issue if you're on shared server. anyways, what error do you get ?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\xampp\htdocs\fahwa\GetPage.php on line 4

Comment: OK. Then you need to enable `cURL` on your machine. See this link: http://www.tildemark.com/programming/php/enable-curl-with-xampp-on-windows-xp.html

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a large lib (~40kb), but PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser should do want you want. :)

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/